# Cypress: if element exist then do something

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am having a problem with if element exist then do something.
As an example:

```
if (cypress.$('.row > .text-right > .btn').length > 0) {
            cy.get('.row > .text-right > .btn').click();
          }
```

the problem here is that cypress aborts the test if the button doesn't exist but that's exactly when cypress shouldn't abort, it should do nothing and continue.

I need a solution for

```
if (element.exists) {
   cy.get(element).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you do it is to get the parent of the element in question, which you know would be displayed every time.

```
cy.get('parent element').then(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.find('.row > .text-right > .btn').length > 0) {
        cy.get('.row > .text-right > .btn').click()
    } else {
        //Do Something
    }
})
```